# CloudKit database fetchRecordWithID error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cloudkit

When i want to fetch record from private database it show me this error:

**Unexpected recordID passed to CKFetchRecordsOperation: CKReference: 0x7fb691c1c300; 8BBDA567-D00A-4603-91A2-D436677F3952:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)**

I don't know why. I took that recordID from my previously fetched record with reference to that "owner" record. So i want fetch that recordID from my reference attribute.

Is something what i do wrong?

Here is my code for this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creationDate > %@", upToDate];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Car" predicate:predicate];
CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *privateDB = [container privateCloudDatabase];
[privateDB performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray*results, NSError*error){
    for (CKRecord*carRecord in results) {
        CarModel *car = [CarModel new];
        CKRecordID *ownerID = [record objectForKey:@"owner"];

        [privateDB fetchRecordWithID:ownerID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError*error){
           // here i expect record with recordID same as recordID in my reference attribute
}
```

Curious is that 8BBDA567-D00A-4603-91A2-D436677F3952 from my error message is right ID when i search for it in Dashboard.

Is any other way to fetch "owner" record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ownerID should be of type CKReference. Then you have to query for the ownerID.recordID like this:

```
CKReference *ownerID = [record objectForKey:@"owner"];
[privateDB fetchRecordWithID:ownerID.recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError*error){
```

Comment: Many thanks for help. I always tried make CKRecord from that reference directly :) But i still have trouble when i have another fetch in completionHandler and one more in that fetch. Is that legal? It always stop working after second fetch an when it start for ( in ) method.

Comment: Maybe i have to add another fetch with addOperation?

Comment: Although you should be able to nest CloudKit operations, I have seen this sort of locking before. In my code I think I have solved this by starting the inner operation on the main queue.

Comment: Yes, indeed I mean https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao At least the EVCloudData object will always go back to the main queue. The underlying dao will not. I wanted to keep that one closer to the CloudKit functionality.

Comment: Ok. I am not very familiar with swift but maybe something there help me solve my problem :) thanks one more time! And merry christmas